# Defining a sequence of models of ZFC satisfying a certain countability requirement

Tags: set-theory

Assuming whatever large cardinal axioms we please, is there a way to define a sequence of sets $M^\omega$ such that for all $n < \omega$, the following hold?

1. $M_n$ is a transitive model of ZFC
2. $M_n \in M_{n+1}$
3. $M_{n+1}$ believes that every element of $M_n$ is countable

I do not especially mind if $M_{n+1}$ believes that $M_n$ is uncountable, but what I would really like is an actual explicit description of such a sequence, as opposed to a mere existence or consistency statement.

**A related question.**

If $M$ is a countable transitive model of ZFC, is there a canonical way of finding another countable transitive model $M'$ such that $M \in M'$ and every $x \in M$ is believed countable by $M'$?

Comment: [Related](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/129704/if-zfc-has-a-transitive-model-does-it-have-one-of-arbitrary-size).

Comment: @AsafKaragila, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just from the assumption that there is a transitive set model of set theory we cannot conclude that there is another one of different height. Similarly, just knowing that there are ordinals $\alpha_1<\dots<\alpha_n$ such that each $\alpha_i$ is the height of a transitive model of set theory, is not enough to conclude that there is a further height $\alpha_{n+1}$. To see this, simply assume that there is such an ordinal $\alpha_{n+1}$. By working in $L$ if needed, we may also assume that $V=L$. We may also assume that $\alpha_{n+1}$ is least possible. Now, consider the model $L_{\alpha_{n+1}}$. In this model, the statement that there are $n$ distinct ordinals that are heights of transitive models is true, but the statement that there are $n+1$ such ordinals is false, by absoluteness considerations. This indicates that there is no "canonical" way of finding models as in your last question.

To ensure that there are $\omega$ such heights, assuming that there is an inaccessible cardinal is an overkill. Assuming that there is a worldly cardinal is also much more than it is needed: If $V_\alpha\models\mathsf{ZFC}$, consider a countable elementary substructure of $V_\alpha$, and its transitive collapse. That gives us a transitive model $M_1$ of countable height. Now consider a countable elementary substructure of $V_\alpha$ with $M_1$ as an element. Its collapse is a transitive model $M_2$, again of countable height, and now $M_1\in M_2$ (since the collapse of $M_1$ is $M_1$), and $M_1$ is countable in $M_2$, by elementarity. Exactly the same argument gives us countable chains of such models, and beyond.

If you want the sequence a bit more explicit than obtained through the procedure just outline, note again that $L_\alpha$ is a transitive model of set theory if there is a transitive model of height $\alpha$. The argument using elementary substructures (and condensation) shows that the least such $\alpha$ is countable, that the second least such ordinal $\beta$ (if it exists) is also countable, and $L_\alpha$ is countable in $L_\beta$, that the third such ordinal $\gamma$ (if it exists) is also countable, and $L_\beta$ is countable in $L_\gamma$, etc.

Comment: I'm finding the argument in the final paragraph very subtle. Could you add a little more explanation about why it works, and how far we can push the argument? For example, let $A \subseteq \omega_1$ denote the set of all $\alpha < \omega_1$ such that $L_\alpha$ is a model of ZFC. Does it follows that for any two $\alpha,\beta \in A$ with $\alpha<\beta$ that $L_\alpha$ is believed countable by $L_\beta$? Does this perhaps only work if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are explicitly definable in some sense?

Comment: If $M$ is a transitive model of set theory, and $M$ has height $\alpha$, then an absoluteness argument gives us that $L^M=L_\alpha$. The condensation lemma for $L$ states that for $\beta$ a limit ordinal sufficiently closed (say $L_\beta$ is a model of $\mathsf{KP}$), if $X\prec L_\beta$ then the transitive collapse of $X$ is $L_\gamma$ for some $\gamma$. "Sufficiently closed" is really not needed, or even that $\beta$ is limit, of that $X$ is fully elementary, but the proof of this gets more involved.

Comment: OK. It follows from this that if for some $\alpha$, $L_\alpha$ is a model of set theory, then the least such $\alpha$ is countable in $L$: Simply take in $L$ a countable elementary substructure of $L_\alpha$, and consider its transitive collapse. Suppose now that $L_\beta$ is a model of set theory and that $\beta>\alpha_0$, where $\alpha_0$ is least such that $L_{\alpha_0}$ is a model of set theory. The argument we just gave shows that $\alpha_0$ is countable, so $L_\beta$ knows this.

Comment: Take in $L$ a countable elementary substructure of $L_\beta$, and consider its transitive collapse $L_{\alpha_1}$. We have $\alpha_1>\alpha_0$ (by elementarity), and $\alpha_1$ is countable in $L$. Etc. As for your question: Let $A$ be the set of countable $\alpha$ with $L_\alpha$ a model of set theory. Let $A'=A\cap\omega_1^L$. If $\beta\in A\setminus A'$, then $L$ does not know that $\beta$ is countable, and naturally neither does any $L_\alpha$. So your question should really be about $A'$ rather than $A$.

Comment: Anyway, in general the answer is no even for $A'$. For instance, if $\kappa$ is inaccessible, then there is a club of $\alpha<\kappa$ with $L_\alpha\prec L_\kappa$, and all these $L_\alpha$ are models of set theory, but some of them are uncountable. If you take a countable elementary substructure, you obtain an $L_{\kappa'}$ with $\kappa'$ countable that nonetheless thinks that many of the $L_\alpha$ models of set theory with $\alpha<\kappa'$ are uncountable as well.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying. I need to think about it all.

Comment: The point is that, before we reach $\omega_1^L$, we will find a stage $\gamma$ where we see a bijection from $\omega$ onto $\kappa'$ (and a bijection from $\omega$ to $L_{\kappa'}$), but the first such $\gamma$ may be much larger than $\kappa'$. Similarly, there may be ordinals $\gamma'<\gamma$ still much larger than $\gamma$ such that some $\alpha<\kappa'$ with $L_{\kappa'}\models$"$\alpha$ is uncountable", is seen in $L_{\gamma'}$ to be countable, while still $\kappa'$ appears to be uncountable in $L_{\gamma'}$.

Comment: The right setting for thinking about these questions is the fine structure theory of $L$, but a nice, pre-fine structure, and very accessible paper that discusses these and similar subtleties is W. Marek, M. Srebrny, *Gaps in the constructible universe*, Ann. Math. Logic, **6**, (1973/74), 359-394.

Comment: *Okay, I'll try to get my hands on it.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume there is an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$. Now $V_{\kappa}$ is a model of 
ZFC form a generic extension $V[G]$ where we collapse $\kappa$ to be countable then 
$V_{\kappa} \in V[G]$ is a model of ZFC and $V[G]$ thinks all elements of $V_{\kappa}$ are countable. Of course $V[G]$ is not a set model just a class model, so we can assume there is another inaccessible cardinal and repeat the same argument.
Thus briefly, we assume there is an infinite sequence of inaccessible cardinals and successively collapse them to be countable. The $V_{\kappa}$ are then your sequence.

Comment: Isn't it easier to just say "Suppose there is an $\omega$ sequence of inaccessible cardinals, pick any cardinal larger then all of them and collapse it to be countable..."? Although just from one inaccessible you get a very long sequence as the OP has asked for.

Comment: Well yes, it was just a process of writing it down.